# Trying to open a pdf with iframe in chrome doesnt work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, vuetify.js

I try to open a document in browser when clicking a button using iframe, in Firefox it opens properly but in Chrome it doesnt. What I have tried is this:

```
   handleOpenDocument(uri){
    var w = window.open('about:blank');
    setTimeout(function(){ //FireFox seems to require a setTimeout for this to work.
        w.document.body.appendChild(w.document.createElement('iframe'))
            .src = uri;
        w.document.body.style.margin = '0';
        w.document.body.style.padding = '0';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.width = '100vw';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.height = '100vh';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.display = 'block';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style['max-width'] = '100%';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.margin = '0';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.padding = '0';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.border = '0 none';
        w.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style['box-sizing'] = 'border-box';
        
    }, 100);
}
```

Any help would be appriciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's working properly on my chrome... Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)! check your version

Comment: I have Version 91.0.4472.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)  and it doesnt work.

Comment: What DOES it do when you click it?

Comment: Nothing, just a blank page opens.